# Isolate int from string

Tags: c#

I have a string which is a word, then =, then a number.

e.g

"RefreshRate=75"

I want to get the integer at the end and store it in an Int. The program uses this value which is stored in an ini file, I need to isolate this value as some other values calculations are based upon it.

How can this be done?

Thank you in advance

Ooooopsss:

Sorry guys, i made a blunder.

The string is actually in the format "RefreshRate=numHz"...i.e "RefreshRate=65Hz"...Im sure this would work, however I get "Incorrect input format error since its adding the Hz as well, and this is throwingthe exception :s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It’s easy! Just use a regular expression!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58646#58646)

```
var m = Regex.Match(input, @"=\s*(-?\d+)");
if (!m.Success)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "The input string does not contain a number.");
return Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

This extracts the first integer that follows a `=` in any string. Therefore, if your input string is `"Frequency2=47Hz"`, it will return `47`.

Answer (score 6):

```
int i=Convert.ToInt32(st.Substring(st.IndexOf('=')+1))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are *sure* the format is *word=value* and is not variant, then this should work for you.

```
int value = int.Parse(line.Split('=').Last());
```

**Edit:** To deal with your <strike>hurts</strike> hertz problem

```
int value = int.Parse(line.Split('=').Last().Replace("Hz", ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
    static int GetIntAfterEqual(string containsIntAfterEqual)
    {
        if(containsIntAfterEqual==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("containsIntAfterEqual");

        string[] splits = containsIntAfterEqual.Split('=');
        if (splits.Length == 2)
            return int.Parse(splits[1]);
        else
            throw new FormatException(containsIntAfterEqual);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
You said it could be "entryname=25hz". This should work for both cases:

```
    static int GetIntAfterEqual(string containsIntAfterEqual)
    {
        if(containsIntAfterEqual==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Match match = Regex.Match(containsIntAfterEqual, @"[\d\w]+=([\d]+)\w*");
        if(match.Success)
            return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        else
            throw new FormatException(containsIntAfterEqual);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that....I had over looked smt :s the string is actually in the format "RefreshRate=numHz"...i.e "RefreshRate=65Hz"...Im sure this would work, however I get "Incorrect input format error since its adding the Hz as well, and this is throwingthe exception :s

Comment: then in the place of this: ` return int.Parse(splits[1]);` put this:  `return int.Parse(splits[1].Replace("Hz", "");` and that will remove the Hz from the end. Also, you'll need to fix the if statement

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use string.Split:

```
int.Parse(s.Split("=")[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you confirm about your text format in word, Then you can use this

```
var word="RefreshRate = 756numHZ";
         int n;
         int.TryParse(word.tolower().Replace("refreshrate","").Replace("=", "").Replace("numhz", "").Trim(), out n);
```

This will also handle case of blank space in your text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var line = "RefreshRate=75";
int number = int.Parse(line.Split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines, assuming that `yourString` contains the text `RefreshRate=75`.

```
int.Parse(yourString.Substring(yourString.IndexOf("=")+1));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that....I had over looked smt :s the string is actually in the format "RefreshRate=numHz"...i.e "RefreshRate=65Hz"...Im sure this would work, however I get "Incorrect input format error since its adding the Hz as well, and this is throwingthe exception :s

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to deal with or checking for "RefreshRate=" or  "RefreshRate==" or  "RefreshRate=Foobar" You can do the following

```
public static class IntParseExtension
    {
        public static bool TryParseInt(this string s, out int i)
        {
            i = 0;     
            bool retVal = false;
            int index;
            string sNumber;
            index = s.IndexOf("=");
            if (index > -1)
            {
                sNumber = s.Substring(index + 1);
                if (sNumber.Length > 0)
                    retVal = int.TryParse(sNumber, out i);
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi mate, thanks for this, i made an error though, its actually "RefreshRate=numHz"...i.e "RefreshRate=65Hz", sry for the mistake, can you offer me further advice please?

Answer (score -3):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int j = 0 ;
        bool flag = false;
        string s = "myage = 400";

        char[]c = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length -1; i++)
        {
            if ((c[i] > '0') && (c[i] < '9'))
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                c[j++] = c[i];
            }
        }
        //for (; j < s.Length - 1; j++)
        //{
            c[j] = '\0';

        s = new string(c,0,j);
        int num = int.Parse(s);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}",num);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

i don't know if there's a better solution ... this one works

Comment: TryParseInt?   Where do you see that method?

Comment: And how are you handling peeling "100" off from "foo=100"

Comment: i didnt see the full Q this one works for cases where after = you have lot of spaces and staff ...